# error No visible @interface.. but there is a visible selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, object

Please take a look at the pictures.. what am I doing wrong?

Ignore that the timeStamp doesn't actually have a date, it's just a placeholder number while I test things..

[image: screenshot of error]
[image: screenshot of interface definition]

I would imbed the images but I don't have enough rep..

Apparently I have to submit code for this post to go through so here's a redundant piece of code that is already shown in the linked images above..

```
// feedItem.m

#import "feedItem.h"

@implementation feedItem


- (instancetype)initWithUsername:(NSString *)username
                        image:(UIImage *)image
                        viewCount:(NSUInteger)viewCount
                        timeStamp:(NSUInteger)timeStamp
                titleDescription:(NSString *)titleDescription {

 self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _username = username;
            _image = image;
            _viewCount = viewCount;
            _timeStamp = timeStamp;
            _titleDescription = titleDescription;
     }
    return self;


}
@end
```

Comment: You wrote `initWithUserame` instead of `initWithUsername` ...

Comment: A little bit of patience to read before posting on stack overflow...

Answer (score 2):

The error is a typo, you have:
`initWithUserame` missing "n".

[image]

The moral to the story: Really read and pay attention to error messages.

Comment: Secondary/alternate moral: make use of autocomplete.

Comment: Tertiary moral: Your Objective-C class names should start with a capital letter.